# Cursor Pagination with RedisJSON

Tags: redis, graphql

I am using Redis to store JSON data with a model that has `Id` and `Name` fields.  My goal is to implement cursor pagination over this data using the `Name` as the cursor.  I realize this isn't unique and I'll need to do some additional work to resolve the issues presented by that using that particular field as the cursor.  However I am struggling to find a way to even begin to implement a basic cursor pagination with Redis commands.  Redis has options for various string operations using the "Search" module but these are limited to search within a given string, nothing with comparisons.  Am I barking up the wrong tree here and cursor pagination is not possible?  Or is there something fundamental I am missing in my design?

Answer (score 0):

> Redis has options for various string operations using the "Search" module but these are limited to search within a given string, nothing with comparisons.

Can you please give an example for a required comparison not within a given string?

The Search query can do some comparisons.

For Cursor, [FT.CURSOR](https://redis.io/docs/stack/search/reference/aggregations/#cursor-api) can be used, for example:

```
127.0.0.1:6379> JSON.SET key1 $ '{"Id": 100, "Name": "foo", "data": "val1"}'
OK
127.0.0.1:6379> JSON.SET key2 $ '{"Id": 200, "Name": "bar", "data": "val2"}'
OK
127.0.0.1:6379> JSON.SET key3 $ '{"Id": 300, "Name": "foo", "data": "val3"}'
OK
127.0.0.1:6379> FT.CREATE idx ON JSON SCHEMA '$.Id' as id NUMERIC '$.Name' as name TAG
OK
127.0.0.1:6379> FT.AGGREGATE idx '@name:{foo}' LOAD 2 @id @name WITHCURSOR COUNT 1
1) 1) (integer) 1
   2) 1) "id"
      2) "300"
      3) "name"
      4) "foo"
2) (integer) 17284697
127.0.0.1:6379> FT.CURSOR READ idx 17284697 COUNT 1
1) 1) (integer) 1
   2) 1) "id"
      2) "100"
      3) "name"
      4) "foo"
2) (integer) 17284697
127.0.0.1:6379> FT.CURSOR READ idx 17284697 COUNT 1
1) 1) (integer) 0
2) (integer) 0
127.0.0.1:6379>
```

Comment: Thanks for the info but the native FT.CURSOR doesn't accomplish what I want.  I want to build something that allows for users to read a "page" at any time and from what I can tell the FT.CURSOR only holds the cursor in memory temporarily.

To boil it down to something simpler, the string comparison I'm looking for would be, in your example, to find all objects where `Name > "bar"`.